# What is the python regular expression to extract string numbers after an identifying expression?

Tags: python, python-re

I've extracted the text from a tax form 990 pdf.
This number as a string: '4,406,019' will be different for each form 990

here are 4 lines of the extracted text with the line I want to work

```
return/
**t ae tr em din- City or town, state or province, country, and ZIP or foreign postal code G Gross receipts $ 4,406,019.**
A rem tue rn nded CITY CITY, STATE 00000-000 H(a)Is this a group return
A tiop nplica- FName and address of principal officer:JOHN DOE for subordinates?~~ Yes X No
```

The regex I tried:

```
total = re.complile('code G Gross receipts $ ([0-9]*)')
total.findall('code G Gross receipts $ ')
```

I want to find every number after the epxression `code G Gross receipts $` 
desired result: `4,406,019`

The issue I'm having, is I dont know how to extract both string numbers and commas in `4,406,019`
I am also struggling to parse the individual lines of the pdf text

Comment: The input doesn't have a number in it.

Comment: To grab a sting of numbers and commas change `[0-9]` to `[0-9,]`

Comment: Did you mean `total.findall('code G Gross receipts $ 4,406,019')`?

Comment: Remember that you need to escape the `$` in the regexp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add comma to `[0-9]`, and escape the `$`.

After matching, use `replace()` to remove the commas before converting the value to a number.

```
total = re.compile(r'code G Gross receipts \$ ([0-9,]*)')
receipts = [int(x.replace(',', '')) for x in total.findall('code G Gross receipts $ 4,406,019')]
print(receipts) # prints [4406019]
```

Answer (score 0):

## Explanation

To extract that number from the text you can use the following structure:

```
re.findall(r"(text_before_the_number [number_pattern]+)", text)
```

In this case, text_before_the_number will be "code G Gross receipts \$ " (Note that for dollar character you need to use the scape character) and the pattern will be "[0-9\,]+" --> this well return a text that contains numbers from 0 to 9 mixed with commas.
The "+" is used for extracting the text until the pattern is False, so that you can get the number pattern "number+comma" for multiple times.
Finally, the hook and eyes are used to allow mixing both numbers and commas.

## Complete code

```
s='**t ae tr em din- City or town, state or province, country, and ZIP or foreign postal code G Gross receipts $ 4,406,019.**\nA rem tue rn nded CITY CITY, STATE 00000-000 H(a)Is this a group return\nA tiop nplica- FName and address of principal officer:JOHN DOE for subordinates?~~ Yes X No'
print(re.findall(r'(code G Gross receipts \$ [0-9\,]+)', s))
```

[Re - regular expression documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)